# Can MYSQL function slow down a query?

Tags: mysql

Guys I am having a lot of `MIN(), MAX(), and CONCAT()` functions in my sql select query, Can this add a lot to the query time? Is this advisable? or should i do the concat, etc. on server side code?

I cant post my query because it wont make sense to you, if it's not the function that's slowing down my query, is it the 42 left joins i have? How to avoid joins?

Comment: Are the relevant columns indexed? It *can* be faster to get the `MIN`/`MAX` of a column if there is a *suitable* index

Comment: In order to get better anwers, please post the query and the execution plan

Comment: I cant @Darhazer, it's too long, but it has 42 left joins, is it bad? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it will not vastly affect the speed. Because MySQL server is fast. If you do that in server side like in Apache then it will take two different time one for fetching from MySQL Database , another for server side function.But if you do that in MySQL it will do the two task in same execution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can. If you apply a function in WHERE clause for example, like `WHERE CONTACT(first_name, last_name) =` it may not be able to use index.